# How do you do an in-place drop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can anybody explain why Array in Ruby doesn't have a drop! method?

Is there a way to drop or slice an array in place?

Comment: good question, the only languages I know that have 'drop' are Database related, like SQL and it's not used in reference to an array element

Answer (score 5):

There's [`slice!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000268). It can take an index (just like `drop`, so `slice!(index)` *is* the in-place `drop` you're looking for), a range, or two parameters for start and end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice!` with a range to accomplish this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.drop(2)
=> [3, 4]
a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

vs

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.slice!(0..1)
=> [1, 2]
a
=> [3, 4]
```